# Reuse blocks of coding vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net I have ex-amount of buttons, which constantly use the same blocks of coding. Surely instead of typing the same code out time and time again there is a way to type it out once and make reference to it, under the relevant buttons...

Dose anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `AddHandler` sample as below:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button_click
    AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf button_click
End Sub
Sub button_click()
    'Add some code here
End Sub
```

You can reference the events from multiple buttons to one sub.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also use multiple event names on the sub: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click - does basically the same thing as the add handler.